# System.NotSupportedException: '$project or $group does not support {document}.' mongodb

Tags: c#, mongodb

When I try to execute join and filter in a select, mongodb 2.4.4 drive throws this exception:

> System.NotSupportedException: '$project or $group does not support
>   {document}.' mongodb

What is issue with below join and filter?

```
var appt = (from col1 in collection1.AsQueryable()
    join col2 in collection2.AsQueryable() on col1.Id equals col2.RefKey into grp
    select new {
        col1, filteredCol = col1.BandId == "" ? grp : grp.Where(t => t.Name ="Hello")
    }).Take(10).ToList();
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your problem is caused not by join or filter, but by your projection. Projection should not include document itself, this just is not supported by MongoDB .Net driver.

So the following query without including `col1` object in the projection will work just fine:

```
var appt = (from col1 in collection1.AsQueryable()
    join col2 in collection2.AsQueryable() on col1.Id equals col2.RefKey into grp
    select new
    {
        //col1,
        filteredCol = col1.BandId == "" ? grp : grp.Where(t => t.Name == "Hello")
    }).Take(10).ToList();
```

There are several possible fixes here. The best choice is to include in projection not the whole document but only the fields that are actually required for further logic, e.g.:

```
var appt = (from col1 in collection1.AsQueryable()
    join col2 in collection2.AsQueryable() on col1.Id equals col2.RefKey into grp
    select new
    {
        col1.Id,
        col1.BandId,
        filteredCol = col1.BandId == "" ? grp : grp.Where(t => t.Name == "Hello")
    }).Take(10).ToList();
```

If however you need the document object itself, you could fetch the whole collection to the client with `.AsEnumerable()` and then use LINQ to objects:

```
var appt = (from col1 in collection1.AsQueryable().AsEnumerable()
    join col2 in collection2.AsQueryable() on col1.Id equals col2.RefKey into grp
    select new
    {
        col1,
        filteredCol = col1.BandId == "" ? grp : grp.Where(t => t.Name == "Hello")
    }).Take(10).ToList();
```

Use this approach as last option because it loads heavily both server and client.